# Local Notifications creations in chatting application when app in foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

How can we create local notification in IOS when app in foreground.I am creating chat app where two persons are chatting while third person interfere then the message which will be sent by third person should be shown in notification like whats app .Can any one please help me ?

Comment: Have you looked at the `UILocalNotification` documentation?
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/fireDate

Answer (score 1):

First you receive the chat message . Then you determine whether the message received is from the person whom you are currently chatting with or third person. When you have determined that the message received is from third person, you use UILocalNotification class in iOS to create notification. For code help, please post your code too.

Comment: we receive push messages in didrecieveRemoteNotification method but  how can  we display notification banner when third person is chatting

Comment: When you receive message in didReceiveRemoteNotification method, check if the message is from third person, if yes use UILocalNotification class and fire one notification from that method.

Comment: I want to create local notification when app in foreground in chatting app when the third person comes into picture so I  am getting notification in background but it is not showing banners can anyone suggest this